# Avoid recycling when merging with R Data Table

Tags: r

I got `tableA`, which contains a numeric variable, `CdTaller` (e.g. 1948675).

I also got `tableB`, which contains two variables: `Id` (e.g. 2513978) and `Name` (e.g. "JOSE MANUEL PEREZ")

I want to add a new column to `tableA`, `Name_Taller`, which contains a name for those `CdTaller` which correspond to the `Id` variable of `tableB`, so I do the following:

```
tableA[, Name_Taller := tableB[Id==tableA\$CdTaller]$Name]
```

However, for those `CdTaller` of `tableA` that are not in `tableB`, R recycles the new variable `Name_Taller`:

```
Warning message:
In \`[.data.table\`(tableA, , \`:=\`(Name, tableB[Id ==  :
  Supplied 867324 items to be assigned to 947871 items of column 'Name'
  (recycled leaving remainder of 80547 items).
```

So for the `tableA$CdTaller == '1320402'`, which can't be found in `tableB`, R still adds a `Name_Taller` which actually corresponds to `CdTaller == '4430219'`, because of this recycling.

The question is: how can I avoid this recycling, so that R only adds a `NA` or empty string to those rows containing a `CdTaller` not found in `tableB`? Is there any parameter in data table I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is `join`-like behaviour that is among others documented here: 
[joins](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html) and [others](https://jangorecki.github.io/blog/2015-12-11/Solve-common-R-problems-efficiently-with-data.table.html)

To make things readable here a version with `dplyr`

```
ex1 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, name = replicate(10, paste(sample(letters[1:5], size = 2), collapse = "")))

ex2 <- data.frame(otherinfo = (1:5)+50, othername = replicate(5, paste(sample(letters[1:5], size = 2), collapse = "")))

dplyr::left_join(ex1, ex2, by = c(name = "othername"))

   id name otherinfo
1   1   ac        NA
2   2   ac        NA
3   3   ab        NA
4   4   da        53
5   5   ab        NA
6   6   cb        NA
7   7   eb        NA
8   8   de        NA
9   9   ad        NA
10 10   ec        52
```